# DB2 SQL connection in Protractor - How To

Tags: sql, protractor

I am new to Protractor and still learning.  In my conf.js file I have (maybe incorrectly?) set up a connection to a database:

```
mysql = require('C:/.../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'username',
    password : 'password',
    database : '//xxxxxxx.xxx.xx:nnnnn/xxxxxxxx'
  });
connection.connect();
```

Then in my test I attempt to query for data to use:

```
//SQL to get Random Invoice Ref
var invRef = SELECT foo FROM table.table 
WHERE condition = myData
ORDER BY RAND()
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

But, it's giving me this error:

```
invRef = SELECT foo FROM table.table ('foo' is underlined with the '^' character)
Exception loading: C:\...\testSpec.js
Error -- fail
```

I suspect I have things set up incorrectly, to say the least.  Can someone tell me the proper way to define a db2 SQL connection in Protractor?  Am I also using it correctly in my test?

Answer (score 1):

Just missing some double quotes there:

```
//SQL to get Random Invoice Ref
var invRef = "SELECT foo FROM table.table " +
             "WHERE condition = myData " +
             "ORDER BY RAND() " +
             "FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;";
```

Given you're setting up SQL access from Protractor NodeJS side of things to load test data from there to fill up forms for example.

Side note: [Doc on Protractor components](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/fcd973b8f8b0/docs/infrastructure.md#how-it-works) will help you separate concerns.

**UPDATE**

#### DB2 SQL in NodeJS

1. Install [IBM client from here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878). Match your server version.
2. Use a NodeJS DB2 library [like this one](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/).

Comment: I guess I kind of need to do that -- load test data from a db into a field.  I had come across this article (https://github.com/protractor-br/guide), which seemed to suggest that it's possible to do, but I thought I just had it set up wrong.

Comment: Then your are just missing the double quotes, the guide is wrong so not your fault. The guide should be `var sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS result FROM database.table WHERE value > 10";`

Comment: Thanks for following up with that, elgalu.  Unfortunately, I am still having connect issues, but I think it's because I did find that our database uses DB2, and not MySQL.  I have to find a node_module for DB2 connections I guess.  Know of any?

Comment: Updated answer with DB2 SQL in NodeJS

Comment: i followed the protractor guide but get Failed: Cannot call method 'query' of undefined when using browser.connection.query();